# Angular 5 Member 'userLogin' not callable

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to call a login function from a modal based form

Login Component.html

```
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button
          (click)="userLogin(emailSignin.value, passwordSignin.value)"
          class="btn loginBtn"
          [disabled]="signin.invalid">

          Submit <fa name="sign-in"></fa>
        </button>

    </div>
```

Login Component.ts

```
  public userLogin(email, password) {
    console.log(email);
    const signIn = new SigninComponent();
    this.userInfo = signIn.userSignIn(email, password);
 }
```

here's the full Component.ts
I've Imported another component that handles the login HTTP request

```
  import { SigninComponent } from '../signin/signin';

  @Component({
     selector: 'app-filter-search',
     templateUrl: './filter-search.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./filter-search.component.css']
  })

  export class FilterSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    userLogin(email: string, password: string) {
       console.log(email);
       const signIn = new SigninComponent();
       this.userInfo = signIn.userSignIn(email, password);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the button is disabled?

Comment: Whats the error ? what do you see in console ?

Comment: it's only disabled if the validation returns false else it's enabled...

Comment: @Arash it does not call the function at all

Comment: which function ? userLogin(email, password) ? Do you get any error in console ?

Comment: @Arash there's no error.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside the function to see if it gets there?

Comment: @callback tsLint says Member 'userLogin' not callable, meaning it does not even call the function.

Comment: Are y ou declaring that function somehow somewhere? Can you show the full login.components.ts?

Comment: In JavaScript it's possible to set variables up to the most top level of your application. Watch this video if you don't know what i mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjyJBL5fkp8 

This could maybe some reason for your trouble. To check out if you have some global variables set you need to debug your code as @callback mentioned and see what variables are available in your constructor, function,...